# Simple: PHP inside Google AppScript

Tags: php, google-apps-script, scriptlet

I want to create a googlescript which catches the current username in wordpress and writes it into a googlesheet.
For this I plan to:

- implement a googlescript webapp into wordpress
- catch the username via `<?php wp_get_current_user(); ?>`

My question is very simple:
I have problems getting a simple php action called via AppScript.
My Code.Gs is:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}
```

My index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
<? echo "Hello world!"; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which gives me the error:

> SyntaxError: Missing ; before statement. (line 2, file "Code")

What am I doing wrong?

*(`<?php echo "Hello world!"; ?>` doens't work too)*

Comment: PHP runs on the server before the HTML is sent to the client.  Apps Script can't run PHP code.  You *might* be able to run code on Google's server to WordPresses server with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` but I'm not sure how you would let Word Presses server know what ever it's needs to know to get the current user.  The `.createTemplateFromFile()` method runs on Googles servers.  You want PHP to run on Word Presses server to get the Word Press user.  I think you would need to have the main HTML coming from Word Press, and Apps Script iFramed into the HTML.  I'm not even sure that is possible.

Comment: I think the best possibility is to run the PHP in Word Press code; get the user; store the user name somehow in the browser, then the Apps Script rendered JavaScript can get the user name.  You can store the user name in a hidden HTML element, or the window object, or Local Storage.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try this and comment it later on

Comment: I tried it this way - inside wp I run the code:
`<?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo '<div id="username" style="visibility: hidden;">' . $current_user->user_login . '</div>';
?>`
Now I tried to catch the ID content from a webapp (in an iframe) but I cannot access the parent element. How can I communicate between both?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure.  Now that your question is a little different and more well defined, you could ask another question.  Someone in the Apps Script community might also know the answer.  [Link to Apps Script community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: Thank you!
Did so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014033/communicate-between-appsscript-and-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

PHP **inside** Google Apps Script is impossible. You can imagine workarounds as @Sandy Good proposed but I think the best thing to do in your case is to develop a WordPress Plugin that will interact directly with a Google Spreadsheet, without passing by a Google Apps Script as [this Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ns-google-sheets-connector/) seems to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doGet(e) {
   var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
   t.data = "GOOD MORNING";
   return t.evaluate();
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
   <? var data2 = "HELLO WORLD"; ?>
   <?= data ?>
   <?= data2 ?>
</body>
</html>
```