# Communicate between AppsScript and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-apps-script, web-applications

I want a Google Apps Script Webapp to catch the current Username from my Wordpress.
I've been working on this a while now but I can't figure it out. 
I tried it this way - inside wp I run the code:

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo '<div id="username" style="visibility: hidden;">' . $current_user->user_login . '</div>'; ?>
```

Now I tried to catch the ID content from a google webapp (in an iframe) but I cannot access the parent element. How can I communicate between both?

Comment: Please read the SO documentation and provide a complete reproducible example with your Google apps script code. Secondly, I think because of iframe restrictions in GAS, you won't be able to access the parent elements. That by a security feature by design.

Comment: Will do so next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can send values to the iframed webapp as parameters.

host page:

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo '<iframe src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?name=' . $current_user->user_login . '"></iframe>'; ?>
```

apps script:

```
function doGet(e) {  
  var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  temp.name = e.parameters.name;
  return temp.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this great idea! I tried it but can't figure out how to get the username?
I uploaded a console picture of the created iframe in my browser:
 http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161207/o3wtg4j3.png

Comment: In Apps Script event objects are passed to the onGet()/onPost() function. Convention names them 'e'. In my example I assign the name to the template object, but you could just as easily do something like `var name = e.parameters.name` and assign the name parameter to a variable.

Comment: `function doGet(e) {  
  var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  temp.name = e.parameters.name;
  return temp.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  }

function Datentransfer() {  
  var logInName = doGet() ;
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID'); 
  var sss= ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  sss.getRange(sss.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[logInName, email]]);  
}`

gives me an error in the console:
`"Cannot read property "parameters" from undefined."`

Comment: The event object is only passed  when you call the webapp from its published url.

Comment: seems clear, otherwise there would be no username catched. I called the webapp on a site of my wordpress page. But it gave me this error ?.?

Comment: Got the solution: it's e.parameter.name 
Now it works - thank you so much!!